# Make JSON popup save or open dialog instead of actual content

Tags: java, jquery, json, struts2, struts

I just started using struts 2 last week, so the answer to my question may be obvious.

I have an opening form with submit that uses an action and executes method to get the data. Then, the only way I could get jQuery to work was to put an action and execute the method that just returns `success` and then I go onto my jQuery grid with a 3rd action.

*whenever I try to execute my program on a browser, the only problem I have is that the JSON string is returned as a file. So when I call the `getJSONResult` action, it gives me a file with the JSON string in it, which I can open or download . .*

**Examples:**

[example 1](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=JSON%20download%20as%20file&um=1&hl=en&client=firefox-a&sa=N&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&biw=1366&bih=575&tbm=isch&tbnid=KmaETq1pqGWqJM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/download-json-from-jax-rs-with-jaxb-resteasy/&docid=A9pzMEPWONMK7M&imgurl=http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/jaxb-json-resteasy.png)

[example 2](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=JSON%20download%20as%20file&um=1&hl=en&client=firefox-a&sa=N&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&biw=1366&bih=575&tbm=isch&tbnid=6dCGCGeSa7di_M%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=596&docid=ecziYCCdZg_cPM&imgurl=http://www.dotnetcurry.com/images/silverlight/26102010image_1.jpg)

So I think it’s a configuration problem, but I can’t find it. I would be very glad if somebody could help me, thanks guys!

Comment: This question is better suited for StackOverflow. And when you search there, you will find that you will need to use a different browser (such as Chrome).

Comment: @geerten : i already posted in there and got no response . suggest me what shall i do

Comment: It is not allowed to crosspost on stackexchange sites. And you are getting much more responses over there, so keep trying at StackOverflow.

Comment: @Geerten . thanks for the link .. but am not looking for some addons . the issue am facing in an enterprise application . so i cant use any addons . i want to fix this programatically or through configuration .

Comment: Keep searching and asking, but not at Programmers (this type of question is not suited for this site). I can't help you with this.

Comment: What browser are you using and what mime type are you serving the JSON response with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely not on the struts side, but on the HTML/JQuery side.

If you click the submit button, the browser wants to do something with the result (open it...). You want to prevent that from happening, and just get the result and handle it yourself.

I managed to use jQuery with struts, and was inspired by this blogpost. The handling of the result is explained there pretty well. You do not have to follow it completely, but it will steer you in the right direction:

http://mycodefixes.blogspot.be/2011/01/using-struts-2-with-json-and-jquery.html